# Records not displayed in Jasper reports properly

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a XML Datasource in jasper reports.

And a sample xml is given below

```
<bill>
     <data>Test1</data>
</bill>
<bill>
     <data>Test2</data>
</bill>
<bill>
     <data>Test3</data>
</bill>
```

Now when I generate Jasper report from Ireport or java program only

Test1 is printed.

I want to print

```
Test1
Test2
Test3
```

Answer (score 1):

When you have multiple tags with similar name, you need to use a "List Component" so that jasper reports scrolls through all of them.
If you will use simple text box, only the first tag data will be displayed.

For using list component, you need to create a data set first.
Then use a list component with sub-dataset as the data set that you created.

Comment: Below is my dataset
<datasetRun subDataset="dataset1">
  <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRXmlDataSource("C://sales.xml")]]></dataSourceExpression>
</datasetRun>
Than also it displays only one record.

Comment: @Ankit : check the xpath, might be some problem with the xPath.

Comment: My XPath is **/roottag/bill/data**  but  still it displays only one row. Not all Test1, Test2 , Test3